# Ищу учебник или материал такого типа

Tags: ios

Доброго времени суток! Понравилась такая книга: Nick Harris - Beginning iOS Programming Building and Deploying iOS Applications - 2014. В ней подробно описывается создание проекта приложения в Хсоде, со всеми этапами и рабочим кодом. После каждого блока - подробно как это работает. Подскажите, кто встречал и какие подобные материалы для дальнейшего изучения?

Answer (score 1):

Эта статья попала в тему: http://habrahabr.ru/post/202960/
Вразумительно и с рабочим кодом!

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).